# when reloading the app through dev menu the modal donot get tear down/disappear

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-elements

When developing, I sometimes leave the modal open when saving code (I use the live refresh), the modal remains open and there is no way to close, so I have to stop the program and restart it.
The app presumably refreshes, but the modal stays on top and cannot be closed
To see exact problem please see this gif what is happening...[click to see gif](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17986#issuecomment-399706088)

Comment: get the hardware back button press event and dismiss your model

Comment: yes I have done that but since hot reloading is on ....so if I save the file, automatic reload occur and that modal does not disappear